# Got mail() multiple or malformed newlines error

Tags: php, email, eol

If there's no attachment, then the email will be sent successfully, but when I tried to add an attachment, it says `mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header`, but I only using 1 `$eol` which means 1 `PHP_EOL`

```
$eol = PHP_EOL;

$headers = "From: ". $_POST['fullname']." <" . $from . ">" . $eol;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: <'.$from.'>' . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

// if attachment is exist then it'll showing an error
if ($filename) {
  $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
  $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
  $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
  $headers .= $content . $eol;
  $headers .= "--" . $separator . "--";
}
```

Comment: The mail body does not belong in the headers. Don't manually construct MIME messages unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Truth be told, you be better off using a tried and tested class.

Comment: @mario is there a website that you recommend that can help me with the problem I got? because I want to use the MIME messages as a practice

Comment: @Script47 well it's a practice purpose, so I think it's OK to use this

Comment: Your call. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯